# load balancer mark "unhealty" new group member instance (ubuntu) after dist-upgrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, apt, gcloud

I've a some VMs (working as web server) behind an [instance group](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceGroups/list) on my GCloud.

As usual maintenance I've update (`apt dist-upgrade`) my "vm-source-image", created a new [template](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceTemplates/list) and add it to my group.

The new members using this template never receive any real working request from the load-balancer and **it is up and running** but *unemployed*.

**Temporary patch**

I do only a partial update (the [security ones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line)) by:

`sudo unattended-upgrade -d`

Here the list of remaining packages that create the problem:

```
# apt list --upgradable

cloud-init/bionic-updates 21.3-1-g6803368d-0ubuntu1~18.04.4 all [upgradable from: 21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~18.04.1]
dnsmasq-base/bionic-updates 2.79-1ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.79-1ubuntu0.4]
gce-compute-image-packages/bionic-updates 20210629.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.0 all [upgradable from: 20201222.00-0ubuntu2~18.04.0]
google-compute-engine/bionic-updates 20210629.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.0 all [upgradable from: 20201222.00-0ubuntu2~18.04.0]
google-compute-engine-oslogin/bionic-updates 20210728.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 20210429.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.0]
google-guest-agent/bionic-updates 20210629.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 20210414.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.0]
libgnutls30/bionic-updates 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.4]
libnetplan0/bionic-updates 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.4]
libpcre2-8-0/bionic 10.39-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 10.36-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2]
netplan.io/bionic-updates 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.4]
nplan/bionic-updates 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.4]
snapd/bionic-updates 2.51.1+18.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.49.2+18.04]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/bionic-updates 27.3~18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.2.2~18.04.1]
```

**A REAL SOLUTION**

Since I've no "custom" package on the machine and the origin of this problem comes from a system update I see no solution except point-out the problem by this post.

Of course I'm monitoring the new updates hoping that a new version of this packages solve the problem, but it's possible ther're no better options?

**More info**

- The group is the backend of an "internal TCP load-balancer".
- The frontend IP address of the load-balancer is **10.0.0.116**
- The old (and working) member IP address is **10.0.0.48**  (seeable the logs)
- The new (and unemployed) member IP address is **10.0.0.54**  (seeable the logs)
- The load-balancer has a simple HTTP health-check know as **HTTPHC1**.
- The instance-group has another simple HTTP health-check know as **HTTPHC2**.

Comparing the access log of an old (and working) member with the new one:

**Log of a old VM member**

```
35.191.1.148 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:34:59 +0000] 10.0.0.48 "GET /?id=HTTPHC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.144 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:35:00 +0000] 10.0.0.48 "GET /?id=HTTPHC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.154 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:35:00 +0000] 10.0.0.48 "GET /?id=HTTPHC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.147 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:35:01 +0000] 10.0.0.48 "GET /?id=HTTPHC1 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.145 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:35:01 +0000] 10.0.0.48 "GET /?id=HTTPHC1 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.151 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:35:02 +0000] 10.0.0.48 "GET /?id=HTTPHC1 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.153 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:35:02 +0000] 10.0.0.48 "GET /?id=HTTPHC1 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
```

**Log of a new VM member**

```
35.191.1.152 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:31:01 +0000] 10.0.0.54 "GET /?id=HTTPHC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.154 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:31:02 +0000] 10.0.0.54 "GET /?id=HTTPHC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
35.191.1.148 "/" - - - [04/Nov/2021:10:31:02 +0000] 10.0.0.54 "GET /?id=HTTPHC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
```

The difference shows the missing of the logs of **HTTPHC1**.

So the new new don't answer to the health check of the load-balancer (HTTPHC1) and don't receive requests and that's the problem.

**Other malfunctions**
The new machine is also unaccessible by browser-window-SSH
[image]

**ADD tcpdump**

Between **HTTPHC1** health-checker and unemployed member:

```
# tcpdump -n host 35.191.1.151
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:30:35.109469 IP 35.191.1.151.61838 > 10.0.0.116.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS  ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
11:30:36.119470 IP 35.191.1.151.61838 > 10.0.0.116.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS  ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
11:30:38.167436 IP 35.191.1.151.61838 > 10.0.0.116.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS  ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
11:30:40.110784 IP 35.191.1.151.59900 > 10.0.0.116.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS  ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
11:30:41.111176 IP 35.191.1.151.59900 > 10.0.0.116.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
11:30:43.159164 IP 35.191.1.151.59900 > 10.0.0.116.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
11:30:45.112162 IP 35.191.1.151.36064 > 10.0.0.116.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS  ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
```

Note that the **destination is load-balancer frontend IP**: 10.0.0.116 and of course they're only Sync packets.

Between **HTTPHC2** health-checker and unemployed member:

```
# tcpdump -n host 35.191.1.148
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:46:12.475724 IP 35.191.1.148.64638 > 10.0.0.54.80: Flags [S], win 65535, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
10:46:12.475788 IP 10.0.0.54.80 > 35.191.1.148.64638: Flags [S.], win 64768, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:46:12.476239 IP 35.191.1.148.64638 > 10.0.0.54.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 256, options [nop,nop,TS], length 0
10:46:12.476239 IP 35.191.1.148.64638 > 10.0.0.54.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:117, ack 1, win 256, options [nop,nop,TS], length 116: HTTP: GET /?id=HTTPHC2 HTTP/1.1
10:46:12.476301 IP 10.0.0.54.80 > 35.191.1.148.64638: Flags [.], ack 117, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS], length 0
10:46:12.476546 IP 10.0.0.54.80 > 35.191.1.148.64638: Flags [P.], seq 1:867, ack 117, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS], length 866: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10:46:12.476659 IP 35.191.1.148.64638 > 10.0.0.54.80: Flags [.], ack 867, win 267, options [nop,nop,TS], length 0
10:46:12.476679 IP 35.191.1.148.64638 > 10.0.0.54.80: Flags [F.], seq 117, ack 867, win 267, options [nop,nop,TS], length 0
10:46:12.476707 IP 10.0.0.54.80 > 35.191.1.148.64638: Flags [F.], seq 867, ack 118, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS], length 0
10:46:12.476879 IP 35.191.1.148.64638 > 10.0.0.54.80: Flags [.], ack 868, win 267, options [nop,nop,TS], length 0
```

Here everything is fine.

### ADD 2021-11-16

After some research I found a missing IP alias in *local* table, no surprise to see that is the frontend-load-balancer IP address, visible as the DST host in the `tcpdump`!

Here the working machine:

```
# ip route show dev ens4 table local
local 10.0.0.48 proto kernel scope host src 10.0.0.48 
local 10.0.0.116 proto 66 scope host 
# uname -r
5.4.0-1056-gcp
```

And here the Fully Updated machine:

```
# ip route show dev ens4 table local
local 10.0.0.54 proto kernel scope host src 10.0.0.54
# uname -r
5.4.0-1057-gcp
```

### ADD 2021-11-20

Now it become a known issue: **[Cloud Networking] Potential Service Issue: Investigating**

> Google Cloud Global TCP Proxy Load Balancers may be unable to serve
> traffic over forwarding rules configured with IPs in the 34.111.0.0/17
> range. A permanent fix for the IP range is In Progress

Comment: Are the new VM's accessible from other VM's in the same VPC ? How did you log in to your new VM ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B the VM is well accessible through his IP  (10.0.0.54). it's the LB (IMO the frontend component) that don't know the real IP of the machine.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the culprit here is the [Netplan](https://netplan.io/) which I'm not familiar with but since it's a networking utility feature and after an upgrade you lost VM's external IP and one of the health checks is failing. Check your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` files before and after an upgrade - are they chenged ?

Comment: You can always try to create another health check that will work and change it in the load-balancer's settings.

Comment: @Wojtek_B if the goal to found the guilty package, yes, checking `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` could be a solution, but my goal is to solve the problem keeping the clean approach possible, eg: create a new machine with ubuntu-20 (should be better if ubuntu-22), or uninstall un-useful package XYZK that is the real origin of the problem.

Comment: @Wojtek_B I don't think is possible by-pass the lack of knoledge of the "group-member-IP" inside the balancer with any real health-check. :(

Comment: Can you try and do the upgrade, but keep the old versions of `libnetplan0`, `netplan.io` and `nplan` packages ?

Comment: Hi @Wojtek_B, I've upgrade the system except the `*netplan*` packages, unfortunately I've the problem, they are not the "troublemakers"

Comment: Maybe just try to install them one by one and check if this "breaks" the configuration. It seems pretty quick solution since there are just a few of them.

Comment: Not so quick, it's imply the full deployment process: power-on-> update -> poweroff-> image->disk->template->deploy + or - 15/20 minute a package. Ok, not building Rome but not so quick

Comment: You can always try installing first half and if after the restar everything works you already know that you have to look for the culprint in the other half. Split it in two again and repeat the process.

Comment: @Wojtek_B the always good b-tree approach :D I'll give a try tomorrow

Comment: @Wojtek_B what do you think of my last *add*?

Comment: Good work nailing it down - did you add the route ? `ip route add to local IP_HERE dev ens4 proto 66`

Comment: @Wojtek_B I just read the answer of EthanWang and now I prefer to know the answer of his question: "why google-guest-agent is not running automatically" ;)

Comment: This looks like the issue with the logging agent and it would be best to report it on [Google's IssueTracker](issuetracker.google.com). I tried reproducing it with simple Ubuntu 16.04 instance and ran sudo apt upgrade with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing, `cloud-init` is the root cause.

According to this [comment](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/pull/1048), `disable_network_activation: true` should be set to avoid conflict with the
`google-guest-agent` service.

The solution is adding the setting in `cloud-init` config.

```
cat > /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-activation.cfg <<EOF
# Disable network activation to prevent \`cloud-init\` from making network
# changes that conflict with \`google-guest-agent\`.
# See: https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/pull/1048

disable_network_activation: true
EOF
```

This file exist in the official image `ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20211103`.

After adding this file, the `google-guest-agent` is running normally.

Comment: I think you did very well, found the solution and creating the bash path (works like a charm). Good job!

Answer (score 0):

I have a machine running Ubuntu 18.04.5, met the same problem after running `apt dist-upgrade`, also upgrade `google-guest-agent 20210629.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.1` (upgradable from: `20210414.00-0ubuntu1~18.04.0`).

Finding that `google-guest-agent` is not running after upgrade.
When I execute `/usr/bin/google_guest_agent` manually, the problem is solved.

Still don't know why `google-guest-agent` is not running automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan, I'll turn your info to google support and I'll keep you update

Comment: I wonder why this problem is not pervasive. Could be because happens only on "customized" system, so for example I disabled "apt-daily.service". Same for you?